# How to plot stream(flow) line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Assume I have 2 matrices `vx` and `vy` that indicate the magnitude of the velocities along x direction and y directions. How can I plot a smooth stream line to indicate the vector field rather than a group of discrete arrows by `quiver`

Thanks for helping me out

Comment: There exist `stream2` and `streamline` but the problem is you have to set initial points.

Comment: What do you mean "initial points"?

Comment: Some point where the steramlines start. I always had the problem to place these points.